# Google Sheets App Script- Add signature when sending e-mail

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a script that will save my Google Sheet spreadsheet as a pdf and email it as an attachment. The code I'm using works, but I don't know how to add a signature to the email I'm sending. Is this possible, and if so; what would be the cleanest way to do it? Here's the code I'm working with. I know, it's not pretty.

```
function displayPrompt() {
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var result = ui.prompt("Please enter email body");

//Get the button that the user pressed.
var button = result.getSelectedButton();
var message = {
to: "someone@somewhere.com",
subject: sheetName,
  body: "Hi team,\n\nPlease find attached the quote that you requested.\n" + 
result.getResponseText() + "\nThank you,\nMe",
name: "My Name",
attachments: 
[SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Quote")]  
}
if (button === ui.Button.OK) {
Logger.log("The user clicked the [OK] button.");
Logger.log(result.getResponseText());
MailApp.sendEmail(message);
} else if (button === ui.Button.CLOSE) {
Logger.log("The user clicked the [Cancel] button.");
}

}
```

Comment: EmailApp is undefined

Comment: Sorry about that, I corrected it. I had copied and pasted an earlier version of my code. Like I said, my code worked, it sends me the email, but I don't know how to add a signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to add the signature to the message of Gmail using `MailApp.sendEmail`

In this case, I think that there are 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, by declaring the signature as the variable, the signature is added.

#### Sample script:

Please modify `message` in your script as follows.

```
var signature = "\nsample signature";  // Added
var message = {
  to: "someone@somewhere.com",
  subject: sheetName,
  body: "Hi team,\n\nPlease find attached the quote that you requested.\n" + result.getResponseText() + "\nThank you,\nMe" + signature,  // Modified
  name: "My Name",
  attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Quote")]
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, by retrieving the sigunature of Gmail, the signature is added.

#### Sample script:

In this sample, Gmail API is used. So, before you use this script, [please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please modify `message` in your script as follows.

```
var signature = "<br>" + Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs[0].signature;  // Added
var message = {
  to: "someone@somewhere.com",
  subject: sheetName,
  htmlBody: ("Hi team,\n\nPlease find attached the quote that you requested.\n" + result.getResponseText() + "\nThank you,\nMe").replace(/\n/g, "<br>") + signature, // Added
  name: "My Name",
  attachments: [SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName("Quote")]
}
```

- The signature retrieved from Gmail is HTML. So in this pattern, `htmlBody` is used instead of `body`.

### References:

- [Method: users.settings.sendAs.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/list)

Comment: Gmail API was enabled but it's still not adding the signature. Here is the code I added. Maybe I have a syntax error, but no error is showing up and the email still sends.                                                   
var signature = "<br>" + Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs[0].signature;   result.getResponseText() + "\nThank you,\nMe".replace(/\n/g, "<br>") + signature,

Comment: @Geo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In your situation, can I ask you about the value of `console.log(Gmail.Users.Settings.SendAs.list("me").sendAs.map(e => e.signature))`? If this is no value, it is considered that in your Gmail, the sigunature is not set. At that time, please confirm it and add the signature at the setting of Gmail and test it again.

Comment: Ok, I checked it and it was showing an empty string. Turns out there was an option unchecked in Gmail, so thanks for the help, it's greatly appreciated!! If I wanted to resize the image in the signature or maybe center, bold, or resize some text included in the signature, how would I do that? Again...thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @Geo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the request of your replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?